# Откуда берёт this функция, запущенная без контекста?

Tags: javascript

В этом скрипте:

```js
x = 2;

var obj1 = {
  x: 3,

  f: function() {
    return (this.x);
  }
};

alert(obj1.f());
var f = obj1.f;
alert(f());
```

непонятно почему объект window является контекстом для функции, которая запускается во втором alert

Если  контекст window прописать явно, то код не будет работать:

```js
x = 2;

var obj1 = {
  x: 3,

  f: function() {
    return (this.x);
  }
};

alert(obj1.f());
var f = obj1.f;
alert(window.f());
```

По этому случаю вопрос: откуда берётся контекст для вызова f() в **первом** примере?

Comment: Простите, но какая между вообще связь между вопросом и якобы дубликатом?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так прямая.

Comment: @Grundy это называется не "прямая", а "пара слов общие". Вопрос-то совершенно о другом!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове функции без указания контекста, контекстом является глобальный объект `window`.

Будет работать:

```js
x = 2; // глобальная переменная == window.x

var obj1 = {
  x: 3,

  f: function() {
    return (this.x);
  }
};

console.log(obj1.f());
var f = obj1.f; // глобальная переменная == window.f
console.log(f());
console.log(window.f());
```

He будет работать:

```js
function test() {
  x = 2; // глобальная переменная

  var obj1 = {
    x: 3,

    f: function() {
      return (this.x);
    }
  };

  console.log(obj1.f());
  var f = obj1.f; // локальная переменная
  console.log(f());
  console.log(window.f()); // ошибка
}
test();
```

*Update*

> Но в моём коде тоже есть явное обращение к window. Оно не работает:

В левом верхнем углу javascript-ового прямоугольника в jsfiddle есть линк-кнопка. Если на нее нажать, выпадает окошко с опциями. У Вас (по умолчанию) "Load Type" выбран "onLoad" - это и создает функцию-обертку вокруг Вашего кода, так что переменные, объявленные с `var` - локальные. Поменяйте эту опцию на "No wrap ..." (не оборачивать).

Comment: Но нет же никакой разницы между моим вторым примером и вашим первым. Но ваш почему то работает

Comment: @cyklop77 есть. У Вас код завернут в функцию, как в моем втором примере

Comment: @Igor все верно. Между вашим **1-ым** и его **2-ым** действительно разницы нет. Есть разница только между тем, где запускается ваш скрипт, а где его.

Comment: @cyklop77 - Посмотрите добавление к ответу про поведение jsfiddle.

Comment: @Igor точно. Я подумал, что себя так ведут только функции, сначала, потому что просто переменную объявил без `var`. Теперь все стало на свои места.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего для понимания считать, что `this` внутри вызванной функции будет равняться "объекту перед точкой" при вызове функции.

Просто вызвав функцию `obj.f()` вы как бы явно указываете, что объект `obj` будет передан в функцию `f` в качестве `this`.

Когда вы определяете новую переменную, которая вызывает ту же функцию, вы вызываете эту функцию, передавая в качестве `this` `window` (явно или не явно):

```
var f = obj.f;
f(); // равносильно `window.f()`
```

В этом случае в функцию передается `window`, в качестве `this`.

Хочу отметить, что этого можно избежать, используя `strict mode`:

```
"strict mode";

var f = obj.f;
f(); // НЕ равносильно `window.f()`
window.f();
```

Сейчас в первом случае `this` внутри функции будет равен `undefined`, что вполне логично, но `window` во втором, что тоже определено явно.

---

Как было выяснено из комментариев, проблема автора вопроса была вызвана средой, где он воспроизводил код. А вообще, как таковой, проблемы не существует.

Comment: Ох чего-то я не понимаю. Но в моём коде тоже есть явное обращение к window. Оно не работает: https://jsfiddle.net/cceycwkc/

Comment: @cyklop77 я вот только что запустил этот код в консоли хрома - выводит сразу 3, а потом 2. Как и должно быть. Протестируйте в других окружениях.

Comment: @cyklop77 и да, на JSFiddle у меня кроме `3` вообще ничего не выводит.

Comment: @cyklop77 В общем, на JSFiddle функциональные объявления и функциональные выражения не попадают в `window` по какой-то неясной мне причине. В этом и проблема. Тестируйте код в нормальных полноценных средах, короче говоря.

Comment: @smellyshovel Я дописал в своем ответе объяснение этого феномена :).

Comment: @smellyshovel, в jsfiddle по умолчанию стоит LOAD TYPE: ONLOAD, что выливается в код: `window.onload = function () { ... }`

Comment: @Grundy Так @Igor уже отметил это`